# Pass a large object of element attribute props to component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, styled-components

Is there a simple way in which I can pass a "large" object of element attributes via an object?

For example:

```
const myAttrs = {
    one: "one",
    two: "two",
    ...,
    fifty: "fifty"
};

return(
    <MyElement data={myAttrs}>Some label</MyElement>
);
```

Such that I can access and set all of these values in the defined element itself...

```
const MyElement = styled.a.attrs(props => ({
    // I want to break down and set each object prop here, rather than
    // do it all individually like...
    //
    // one: props.one,
    // two: props.two,
    // ...
}))`
    // CSS here...
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `spread` operator

```
<MyElement {...myAttrs}>Some label</MyElement>

const MyElement = styled.a.attrs({one, two, three} => ({
   // you can access these properties directly by using one for props.one and so on
```

Comment: How would one then access this in the definition?

Comment: myAttrs.one would be equivalent to props.one and so on

Comment: In react you can't directly set parent variables from child, so to set them you will have to pass setter methods as props

Comment: So there is no easy way of cutting out the step of doing something like `{one:props.one, two: props.two, ...}`?

Comment: This is exactly what it does. I will put the child in my answer as well

Comment: But yes you will have to mention them all in arg list

Comment: On the back of your spread work, I found a way in which I think I can include all of the attributes I like. Basically we can do as you suggested: `<MyElement {...myAttrs}>Label</MyElement>`, but then in the `const` we can access easily by instead of individually highlighting the attributes, we can simply write `export const MyElement = styled.a.attrs(props => props)\`...\`` and this will pass through *ALL* props defined in the object, and attach them to the HTML element as you have defined them.

Comment: That's great, makes sense:)

Answer (score 0):

Pass large number of props from parents to child

```
 <Content
      accounts={this.props.accounts}
      showBalance={this.props.showBalance}
      withdraw={this.props.withdraw}
      deposit={this.props.deposit}
      current={this.props.current}
      depositAmount={this.props.depositAmount}
      handleDeposit={this.props.handleDeposit}
      handleRm={this.props.handleRm}
      amounts={this.props.amounts}
      getWithdraw={this.props.getWithdraw}
    />;
```

could be replaced with

```
 <Content {...this.props} />
```

You can destructed in child component

```
    const {accounts,showBalance,withdraw,.....,getWithdraw} = this.props;
```

Comment: Crikey, that'll be a long haul! I can see what you mean though. Perhaps something along the lines of what @kooskoos has suggested would be more appropriate, spreading the data.

Comment: @physicsboy please see the above code i have edited it. I hope it may full fill your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

On the back of the spread work done by @kooskoos, I found a way in which I think I can include all of the attributes I like.

Basically we include the spreaded object in the HTML

```
<MyElement {...myAttrs}>Label</MyElement>
```

then in the `const` we can access these props easily by *(instead of individually highlighting the attributes)*, we can simply write as such:

```
export const MyElement = styled.a.attrs(props => props)`...`
```

and this will pass through ALL props defined in the object, and attach them to the HTML element as you have defined them.

```
<MyElement one="one" two="two" three="three" ...>Label</MyElement>
```